# Allow the images to be able to update themselves after each capturing of images

Tags: java, android, image

I need help with gridview images being able to update itself after each time I capture new image. Right now my code allow me to capture images using the camera button and save it to a specific folder in SD card. My problem is whenever I capture a new image, I need to reopen my application in order for the newly captured images to appear, so I need help to make the images auto update itself after each capture. Can someone help me with it? Below is some snippets of my code.

MainActivity.java

```
public class Uploads extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

            ImageView btnAllShops, btnFavourites, btnUploads, btnSettings, btnBuys,
            btnTakePhoto;
            GridView gvUploads;
            String name = null;
            private String description, category, price, imagepath;
            final static int cameraData = 0;
            private Cursor cursor;
            private int columnIndex;
            public static final String PHOTO_ALBUM = "Neatpicks";

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploads);
        findViewById();
        onBackPressed();

    // // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
    // String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
    // // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
    //
    // cursor = managedQuery(
    // MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
    // //Which
    // // columns
    // // to
    // // return
    // null, // Return all rows
    // null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
    //
    // // cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    // MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    // // projection,
    // // MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
    // // new String[] {"%/Neatpicks/%"},
    // // null);
    //
    //
    // // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
    // columnIndex = cursor
    // .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // request only the image ID to be returned
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
    cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
            new String[] { "%Neatpicks%" }, null);
    // Get the column index of the image ID
    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

    gvUploads.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

}// onCreate

private void findViewById() {
    btnAllShops = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnAllShops);
    btnFavourites = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnFavourites);
    btnUploads = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnUploads);
    btnSettings = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSettings);
    btnBuys = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnBuys);
    btnTakePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnTakePhoto);

    gvUploads = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvUploads);

    btnAllShops.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnFavourites.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnUploads.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSettings.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnBuys.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnAllShops:

        break;

    case R.id.btnFavourites:
        Intent iF = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Favourites.class);
        startActivity(iF);

        break;

    case R.id.btnUploads:
        Intent iU = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Uploads.class);
        startActivity(iU);

        break;

    case R.id.btnSettings:
        Intent iS = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(iS);

        break;

    case R.id.btnBuys:
        Intent iBuy = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Buys.class);
        startActivity(iBuy);

        break;

    case R.id.btnTakePhoto:
        Intent i = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
        break;

    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        Intent goMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                EditUploads.class);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bs);
        goMain.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
        startActivity(goMain);
    }
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
        context = localContext;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(context);
        // Move cursor to current position
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        // Get the current value for the requested column
        int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
        // obtain the image URI
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                Integer.toString(imageID));
        String url = uri.toString();
        // Set the content of the image based on the image URI
        int originalImageId = Integer.parseInt(url.substring(
                url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length()));
        Bitmap b = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getContentResolver(), originalImageId,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
        i.setImageBitmap(b);
        i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250, 250));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        // i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
        return i;

    }
}}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

// ---returns the number of images---

// ---returns the ID of an item---
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

// ---returns an ImageView view---

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridView finds out the variable values at the moment GridView is created.  If this value changes, the display will not be updated unless there is a refresh routine or the onCreate() routine is run again.  In order to refresh the images, I suggest you take a look at the code for [ImageLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856980/android-image-loader).

ImageLoader creates a separate thread that downloads and updates images that are placed in its queue (actually stack).

CursorAdapter code

```
 public class MapDataFileCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private LayoutInflater sInflater;
private int fNameColumn;
private int fSnippetColumn;
private int fImageUrlColumn;

public MapDataFileCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);

    fNameColumn = c.getColumnIndex(MapDataFileDBAdapter.KEY_NAME);
    fSnippetColumn = c.getColumnIndex(MapDataFileDBAdapter.KEY_SNIPPET);
    fImageUrlColumn = c.getColumnIndex(MapDataFileDBAdapter.KEY_IMAGEURL);

    sInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.poiDocInfoNameRow);
    name.setText(cursor.getString(fNameColumn));

    TextView info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.poiDocInfoSnippetRow);
    info.setText(cursor.getString(fSnippetColumn));

    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.poiDocInfoLogo);
    String imageUrl = cursor.getString(fImageUrlColumn);

    if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(imageUrl)) {
        image.setEnabled(true);
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        MapDataFileListView.getImageLoader().DisplayImage(imageUrl, null, image);           
    } else {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_globe);            
    }

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return sInflater.inflate(R.layout.mapdatafile_row, null);
}
```

And the code that specifies the datasource in ListActivity

```
    private void setUpListViewIfNeeded() {
    if (poiListView == null) {
        poiListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    }
    if (poiListView != null) {

        Cursor data = poiDbhelper.getCursorOfAllEntries(true, null);
        if (data != null) {
            dataSource = new MapDataFileInstalledCursorAdapter(poiListViewContext, data, 0);
            poiListView.setAdapter(dataSource);             
        }
        showToastMessage(getString(R.string.toast_mesg_records_read) + " " + data.getCount());
    }
}
```

Very little difference between GridView and ListView.  It should be quite easy from here.  Also, there are two more classes associated with ImageLoader (or at least the version I am using).  Give me an email address and I will send you all three of them (I can't remember where on the Internet I got them off).

Comment: do i have to create a new class for this imageloader?

Comment: ImageLoader is a new class.  You need to add calls to DisplayImage in the CursorAdapter (see added code above).  There are other classes associated with ImageLoader but the class can run by itself.

Comment: Is it okay for you to teach me how to integrate your code into my code, not really very sure about how ImageLoader works with my code.

Comment: It is not my code but it is a great piece of software and I wished I had written it :)  I usually use it with ListActivity which has a CursorAdapter.  I will add some more code to my first reply.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You might want to send them to this email. magicianboy_9@hotmail.com